# how do you make geom_points transparent

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this plot and when group2 = 0 I set the size of the point to 0 and the alpha to .000000000001 because I'd like to make those points invisible. But you can still see the circle on the charte. Any idea how to make that circle completely invisible?

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
dat = data.frame(label = c("A","B","C","D"), group1 = c(1,2,3,.02), group2 = c(3,4,5,0), color1 = c("lightblue","lightblue","lightblue","lightblue") ,
                 color12 = c("blue","blue","blue","blue"))

dat$sizze = ifelse(dat$group2 ==0 ,0, 2 )
dat$alpha = ifelse(dat$group2 ==0 ,0.0000000000001, 1 )


p1 <- ggplot(dat, aes(x = label, y = group1, fill = color1))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")  +
  geom_point(data = dat, aes(x = label, y = group2, color = color12, size = sizze, alpha = alpha))

p1 + 
  scale_size(guide='none', range=c(2) ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('lightblue' = 'lightblue'),
                    name = 'bar legend')+
  scale_colour_manual(values = c('blue' = 'blue'),
                      name = 'point legend')
```

Comment: ??? If you want to make the point "completely invisible", why plot it at all? You could `subset` the data, and exclude any rows where `alpha < threshold`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to not plot your point, it is probably best to just subset the data in the `geom_point`. You could try changing your `geom_point` to:

```
geom_point(data = dat[!(dat$group2==0),], aes(x = label, y = group2, 
           color = color12, size = sizze, alpha = alpha))
```

Which give this plot:

[image]